# Need to import all components in index to show import suggestion - turborepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, turborepo

Well, this problem is common, but it puzzles me that there isn't a better solution.

In turborepo as well as in other projects, if you have a package with several components, and you want to make it visible to other packages, each component of this package must be exported from a single index.

**Like this:**

[image]

```
//index.tsx

//Button
export * from "./atoms/Button"

//TextField
export * from "./atoms/TextField"
```

[image]

But let's assume we have thousands of components, we would need to continue exporting from its own declaration, and then import it into the project index, and only then make it visible to other packages.

Alright, the problem is the manual process of doing this, managing which package still exists, removing an export, etc, unnecessary dynamics.

I am able to use the components without using this index file, the problem is that vscode is not able to suggest the components without using the index.

**Take a look:**

[image]

[image]

```
import TextField from '@ui/atoms/TextField'
```

If I put the right path, the component is imported normally, without errors, but without vscode suggestion.

**Is there any alternative solution? Is there any way to automatically generate this index with all exports ?**

**To simulate** this just use [turborepo example project](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/getting-started/create-new), there must be other ways too, it's not turborepo related problem but package management.

```
npx create-turbo@latest
```

I also had to change the packge.json of the shared-package.

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint **/*.tsx"
  },
```

Here is also the code: [GitHub - Turborepo Basic](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/basic)

Comment: I paused this search, if you find it, share it with us

Comment: any solution to this date ?